# How to combine all features of Material UI Typography and Box Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a custom component combining Material UI Typography and Box Component. But I do see some compilation issues like if I use fontWeight property to Box component it automatically converts the styles, which is not happening in customization process. I have been to many blogs and everyone suggests not to have this approach, but there is a requirement for us to have a re-usable component which can supports multiple css attributes.

This is what I have tried:

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import {BoxProps, TypographyProps} from '@material-ui/core';

export type TypographyBoxProps = BoxProps & TypographyProps;

export const Typography: FC<TypographyBoxProps> = (props) => {
  const {children, component: Component = 'p', ...rest} = props;

  return <Component {...rest}>{children}</Component>;
};
```

This is how the above final compilation element looks like, which is incorrect, expectation is it should convert the font weight to actual css:

```
<h1 mb="3" font-weight="200" variant="h1" color="secondary">Hello Component!!!</h1>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I think this is possible only on the pro version no?